# PHP 7 Group Use Declarations for Short Standard Namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, php-7

So PHP 7 has nice group use declarations for namespaces, like [this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/group_use_declarations):

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\{
  Helper\Table,
  Input\ArrayInput,
  Input\InputInterface,
  Output\NullOutput,
  Output\OutputInterface,
  Question\Question,
  Question\ChoiceQuestion as Choice,
  Question\ConfirmationQuestion,
};
```

But for some reason the same syntax does not work for one-word namespaces (all from the same `global` namespace, as [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) requires), like this:

```
use {ArrayAccess, Closure, Countable, IteratorAggregate};
//or 
use \{ArrayAccess, Closure, Countable, IteratorAggregate};
```

Both gives an error (while IDE does not show any syntax issues):

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) or \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in ...
```

Simple standard `use` of multiple namespaces works as intended:

```
use ArrayAccess, Closure, Countable, IteratorAggregate; //no errors
```

So is there any reason why such syntax can not be applied here?

Comment: Just curios, what happens if you try: `use \\{ArrayAccess, Closure, Countable, IteratorAggregate};`?

Comment: Note that the syntax you are trying to use is unnecessary in the first place, since you can leave out the brackets for the same effect. That's probably why it's not supported.

Comment: It needs a valid namespace before the `{` , empty or ` \ ` is not such a thing.

Comment: @keksnicoh, syntax error even on IDE level

Comment: @deceze yes, it's possible, I thought about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) As "Stefan W" wrote his comment on [PHP: Traits - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#113047):

> "use" for namespaces always sees its arguments as absolute (starting at the global namespace):

This is why you had no errors in your example:

```
use ArrayAccess, Closure, Countable, IteratorAggregate; //no errors
```

The second part is that if we read the [PHP namespaces specification](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/18-namespaces.md#namespace-use-declarations), we can see that you used the following valid pattern:

```
use   namespace-use-clauses   ;
```

or if we read the ["Zend language parser"](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f153f11595e9685e8ab4743c19d64397d34bc9e1/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L329), we can see the same thing:

```
    |   T_USE use_declarations ';'
```

where **T_USE** is the "use" keyword in our php code and **use_declarations** is a list of 1 or more **use_declaration** elements (basically, namespaces names, you will see below) separated by comma(s).

The interesting part is that if we rewrite the example above like this:

```
use \ArrayAccess, \Closure, \Countable, \IteratorAggregate;
```

it will also work! We can see this pattern [here in the specification](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/09-lexical-structure.md#grammar-qualified-name) and we actually have this pattern in the Zend language parser, because each **use_declaration** element matches the following pattern:

```
use_declaration:
    unprefixed_use_declaration
|   T_NS_SEPARATOR unprefixed_use_declaration
;
```

Where **T_NS_SEPARATOR** is a backslash - "\".

2) What about group use declarations.

Well, if this example works fine:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\{Helper\Table, Input\ArrayInput, Input\InputInterface, Output\NullOutput, Output\OutputInterface, Question\Question, Question\ChoiceQuestion as Choice, Question\ConfirmationQuestion};
```

why can't we write something like this?:

```
use {ArrayAccess, Closure, Countable, IteratorAggregate};
//or 
use \{ArrayAccess, Closure, Countable, IteratorAggregate};
```

Answer: that is because we are not matching any of the valid patterns from the specification, neither from the Zend language parser:

```
group_use_declaration:
    namespace_name T_NS_SEPARATOR '{' unprefixed_use_declarations possible_comma '}'
|   T_NS_SEPARATOR namespace_name T_NS_SEPARATOR '{' unprefixed_use_declarations possible_comma '}'
;
```

There is **no** pattern like:

```
'{' unprefixed_use_declarations possible_comma '}'
//or
T_NS_SEPARATOR '{' unprefixed_use_declarations possible_comma '}'
```

for group use declarations.